# Bigquery Datetime format csv to bigquery YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]

Tags: csv, datetime, google-bigquery

*Read many datetime formating questions out there, but can't find one that fits. -Obviously- already tried to google this.*

I have some datetime info on a csv file that I'm uploading to bigquery to create a new table. BQ specifies that the [format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) for any datetime columns must be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

They also gave the example:

```
Event            | UNIX      | Datetime String
---------------------------------------------------------
"Neil Armstrong  | -14182916 | 1969-07-20 20:18:04
sets foot on     |           | 1969-07-20 20:18:04 UTC
the moon"        |           | 1969-07-20T20:18:04
```

However when I format the datetime column as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in excel, and upload that csv to BQ, I get the error message:

```
Errors:
mediaupload-snapshot: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. 
Rows: 1; errors: 1. (error code: invalid)
query: Could not parse '2017/11/22 14:47:23 SGT' as a timestamp. 
Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]; Could not parse 
'2017/11/22 14:47:23 SGT' as datetime for field Start_Time (position 0) 
starting at location 492 (error code: invalidQuery)
```

When I try to convert the csv column to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]` using excel, I'm told it's not a legal format.

When I try `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS \U\T\C` or `YYYY-MM-DD\THH:MM:SS`, it looks good in excel, BUT I get the same error message from BQ as above.

**What's the right way to store data in CSV so that it's compatible with BQ?**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @VivianSpencer Unfortunately not. In the end, I streamed the data in another way.

Comment: I actually got this working using the following format:
`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.00Z`.

I was trying to import a datetime field from mysql and used the following function to forrmat the value `DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S.00Z')` in my select query

Comment: Cool thanks! I don't have a use for this problem now, but would you like to post that as a solution below? It might help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue and got this working using the following format:
`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.00Z`. I used the following examples from the TIMESTAMP data type as a reference:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#examples

At the time I was attempting to import a DATETIME field from MySQL and used the following function to format the value `DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S.00Z')` in my SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the exact format which you'll be uploading into BigQuery if you open the file with Notepad and not Excel.  What you see in excel may not be what the data actually looks like.

Answer (score -3):

Try skipping the header before uploading to BQ:

[image: BQ import snapshot]